# Non-EU citizen travelling with EU citizen (Irish spouse) to Turkey; do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, turkey, eu-citizens, visa-free-entry

Am a non EU citizen but my husband is. We live and work in UK and I have a residential permit. I'm looking to book a holiday to Turkey for my hubby and I for 5 days. Do I need to apply for a visa to do so?

Comment: Turkey is not an EU member country, so travelling with your (EU citizen) spouse probably won't give you extra rights with regards to Turkey... What is *your* citizenship?

Answer (score 7):

As it already has been stated weather your husband is an EU citizen is irrelevant. What counts is your nationality and personal information. Whether you need a visa primarily depends on your nationality. Facts like remaining validity of your passport, your country of residence, might have an effect as well. The [IATA](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/TR-Turkey-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) has a handy webservice where your can check whether you need a visa or not. If you are a canadian born in 1980 living in the UK, with a valid passport until 2015 (some random data I entered) you don't need a visa.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on your visa when traveling with someone else. Every person needs their own visa to justify their own permit to enter the country.

Since Turkey is not a part of the EU, you will have to find out by each of your nationality if you are able to enter Turkey without a visa.

Answer (score 1):

Check the official Turkish website: https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/

There is a huge list of countries whose citizens don't need a visa, and another huge list of countries whose citizens can buy a visa online cheaply. Quite unpredictable which category you fall into. Wikipedia has a nice overview https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey .

If you and your husband have different nationalities then each of you needs their own visa, depending on nationality (or possibly no visa at all).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a visa to Turkey depending on your nationality, purpose of visit and length of stay, not depending on your partner.